# Why Linux 'cp' command did not copy files from soft link completely？

Tags: linux, symbolic-link, cp

I have a soft link which linked to a nested image folders (thousand of images)

```
(DRS) xzhan@4daf823ea86f:~$ ls -l voc12_root
lrwxrwxrwx 1 xzhan aiml 30 Mar 16 15:20 voc12_root -> /mnt/Data/Datasets/voc12_root/
```

and I want to copy the images in one of its sub-folder:

```
(DRS) xzhan@4daf823ea86f:~$ cp -r voc12_root/VOCdevkit/VOC2012/ ~/DRS_dataset
```

The 'cp' command should work fine, but it seems that some images loss during the copy process and I can't troubleshot it. Any one can help me?

```
(DRS) xzhan@4daf823ea86f:~$ du -b voc12_root/VOCdevkit/VOC2012/
5341193450      voc12_root/VOCdevkit/VOC2012/superpixels
74008   voc12_root/VOCdevkit/VOC2012/ImageSets/Segmentation
2352400 voc12_root/VOCdevkit/VOC2012/ImageSets/Action
29596   voc12_root/VOCdevkit/VOC2012/ImageSets/Layout
7205056 voc12_root/VOCdevkit/VOC2012/ImageSets/Main
9665156 voc12_root/VOCdevkit/VOC2012/ImageSets
18642246        voc12_root/VOCdevkit/VOC2012/Annotations
9322572 voc12_root/VOCdevkit/VOC2012/SegmentationObject
1922590472      voc12_root/VOCdevkit/VOC2012/JPEGImages
9359317 voc12_root/VOCdevkit/VOC2012/SegmentationClass
8110414228      voc12_root/VOCdevkit/VOC2012/

(DRS) xzhan@4daf823ea86f:~$ du -b DRS_dataset/
1922565896      DRS_dataset/JPEGImages
7205056 DRS_dataset/ImageSets/Main
74008   DRS_dataset/ImageSets/Segmentation
2352400 DRS_dataset/ImageSets/Action
29596   DRS_dataset/ImageSets/Layout
9665156 DRS_dataset/ImageSets
1922565896      DRS_dataset/VOC2012/JPEGImages
7205056 DRS_dataset/VOC2012/ImageSets/Main
74008   DRS_dataset/VOC2012/ImageSets/Segmentation
2352400 DRS_dataset/VOC2012/ImageSets/Action
29596   DRS_dataset/VOC2012/ImageSets/Layout
9665156 DRS_dataset/VOC2012/ImageSets
5341172970      DRS_dataset/VOC2012/superpixels
9322572 DRS_dataset/VOC2012/SegmentationObject
9359317 DRS_dataset/VOC2012/SegmentationClass
18646342        DRS_dataset/VOC2012/Annotations
8110373268      DRS_dataset/VOC2012
5341172970      DRS_dataset/superpixels
9322572 DRS_dataset/SegmentationObject
9359317 DRS_dataset/SegmentationClass
18646342        DRS_dataset/Annotations
16220746536     DRS_dataset/
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please [edit] and give an example of what you mean. It will probably be like "I expected the number next to `bar` to be `N` in the second list, because it's `N` for `foo/bar` in the first list; but it's actually `M` in the second list". Comparing things "manually" is not fun. If you think some numbers are wrong, point at them explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to copy symlinks fully and preserve them as a symlink, you can use the -H flag in addition to -r one. Therefore your command would be as follows:

`cp -rH voc12_root/VOCdevkit/VOC2012/ ~/DRS_dataset`

If you don't want to preserve the symlink, but make a directory out of it, you can use the -L flag:

`cp -rL voc12_root/VOCdevkit/VOC2012/ ~/DRS_dataset`

Hope that helps. :)

Comment: Thank You! It works. Could you provide more info about the mechanism of copying the file via soft link? e.g. Why it requires option 'H'.

Comment: I want to vote this answer but I can't. I am new in StackExchange and I don't have 15 reputation. Just want you to know I appreciate your answer and it helps me a lot.

Comment: Hey, 

first of all: glad it works :)
And ofc. the flag -H is just there to tell the cp command to follow the symlink and also keep it a symlink. Contrary to using -L you therefore have an 1:1 copy with working links afterwards. With the flag -L you're telling cp to follow the symlink, but copy it like it was a folder. Therefore the symlink gets lost, although the files of the folder it was directing to will be there as expected. 
Feel free to read further in [man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cp.1.html)

Comment: Hi syseng21. Thank you for your clarification. The manual just give me one simple sentence about each option. So I am still confusing.

My understanding about the command "cp -rL" is that it will just copy the link as symlink and it wont take long time.
However, I did tests which copying the data set via soft-link with option "L" and "H". Both of the test take more than 1min. Hence, for the test with "H", it doesn't like just simply copy the link (treat it as a link and copy it) and it probably copy the whole data set, which doesn't match my understanding. Can you give me some tips?